# C++/CLI ref class not getting freed

Tags: memory, garbage-collection, c++-cli

I have an unmanged class and a ref class which ar logically connected:

```
public ref class RefBlah
{
   ~RefBlah();
   !RefBlah();

   internal:

   UnManagedBlah* m_unmanaged;
}

public class UnManagedBlah
{
    public:
    gcroot<RefBlah^> refBlah;
}
```

The **RefBlah** class always creates an instance of **UnManagedBlah** which holds a reference to the object that created it.

Now, when I create an instance of **RefBlah** in a C# application, it just doesn't get freed when it get out of scope. (I've waited and seen all the other objects get freed, but it refuses to remove itself).

As far as I know, if they were both regular .Net objects, they would both be collected when the class gets out of scope because although the reference count does not reach 0. And that's because there's no refernce root to the objects from the main stack.

Does .NET GC treat references from unmanaged classes differently ?

How can I change the design so that **RefBlah** will be destroyed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a circular reference problem. `RefBlah` won't get GC'd until the reference in `UnManagedBlah` is GC'd which will only happen when you delete the pointer in `RefBlah` etc..

If you need to have a reference inside the unmanaged class then perhaps it should be a weak reference? Have a look at the [`GCHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.aspx) struct:

> The GCHandle class is used with the
>   GCHandleType enumeration to create a
>   handle corresponding to any managed
>   object. This handle can be one of four
>   types: Weak, WeakTrackResurrection,
>   Normal, or Pinned. When the handle has
>   been allocated, you can use it to
>   prevent the managed object from being
>   collected by the garbage collector
>   when an unmanaged client holds the
>   only reference. Without such a handle,
>   the object can be collected by the
>   garbage collector before completing
>   its work on behalf of the unmanaged
>   client.

Comment: Nice, didn't know you can create a weak reference in C#. Makes sense that they would have it :)

Comment: Circular references don't affect .Net as much. The problem was that because **UnManagedBlah** is unmanaged, CLI doesn't free the referenced object while it's referenced in unmanageed code. But the solution solved the problem anyway.